# How to find a nearest hyperplane to a point with some conditions?

Tags: geometry

Let $S=\{P_{1},P_{2},...,P_{m}\}$ be a set containing distinct points in $R^{3}$.  Suppose $P_{1},P_{2},...,P_{m}$ be adjacent points to $P$, where $P$ is the vertex of the polytope and any three points of the set are non-collinear.  The problem is how can we determine the nearest hyperplane formed by points of $S$(outer normal vector) to the point $P$  such that  the remaining points, except those points which form the hyperplane, lie on the half space that does not contain the point P.  You can consider $P$ as a vertex of a polytope and $P_{1},P_{2},...,p_{m}$ as its adjacent vertices. You can extend to $R^n$ if possible.